# How to auto-refresh POST a tab?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

I'm looking for a way to auto-refresh POST a page. By that, I mean the browser will resubmit the form automatically, just like if we had manually clicked the "Continue" button below:

[image]

Add-ons I've tried:

1. [RefreshMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ljngnafhejmefmijjoedbclkadhacebd)
2. [Auto Refresh Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oilipfekkmncanaajkapbpancpelijih)
3. [Easy Auto Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc)
4. [ChromeReload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/njoipeaphfnaplplihpbgndfojhdhmjo)
5. [Page Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmooaemjmediafeacjplpbpenjnpcneg)

However they only allow auto-refresh GET requests.

What may be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of browser automation tools which you could look at.  They are mostly used for testing web applications, so they can be a little complicated (but very powerful).

Probably the best place to start is [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/).  This one is geared around recording normal user actions in a browser and playing them back.

If you find you need something more powerful, both Selenium and WatiN are very good.

Comment: Hmm, I don't need anything powerful. Just a simple refresh-this-tab-every-minute will be fine (of course it needs to resubmit POST data).

Answer (score 1):

The Mozilla extention Check4Change resubmits POST data.

Comment: question is for Chrome, not firefox